# What is the need of private constructor in C#?

Tags: c#

What is the need of private constructor in C#?
I got it as a question for a C# test.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For example if you have a class that should only be created through factory methods. Or if you have overloads of the constructor, and some of them should only be used by the other constructors. Probably other reasons as well =)

Comment: Actually when you have to control the class instantiation, that could be through a factory or a singleton pattern.

Comment: @André: And your point is? That would still be a reason for having private constructors. Unless your factory class is a different class, but that is a different topic.

Answer (score 12):

If you know some design pattern, it's obvious: a class could create a new instance of itself internally, and not let others do it.
An example in Java (I don't know C# well enough, sorry) with a singleton-class:

```
class Meh 
{
  private Meh() { }
  private static Meh theMeh = new Meh();
  public static Meh getInstance() { return theMeh; }
}
```

Comment: Humorously enough, this Java is also valid C# -- perhaps you know more C# than you think. ;)

Answer (score 11):

Whenever you want to prevent direct instantiation of a class from outside of it, you'll use a `private` constructor. For example, prior to C# 2.0 which introduced `static` classes, you used a `private` constructor to accomplish roughly the same thing:

```
sealed class StaticClass {
     private StaticClass() {
     }
     public static void DoSomething() {
     }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

When you want to prevent the users of your class from instantiating the class directly. Some common cases are:

- Classes containing only static methods
- Singletons

Answer (score 7):

I can can recall few usages for it:

- You could use it from a static factory method inside the same class
- You could do some common work inside it and then call it from other contructure
- You could use it to prevent the runtime from adding an empty contructure automatically
- It could be used (although private) from some mocking and ORM tools (like nhibernate)

Answer (score 2):

For example when you provide factory methods to control instantiation...

```
public class Test(){

  private Test(){
  }

  void DoSomething(){
    // instance method
  }

  public static Test CreateCoolTest(){
    return new Test();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Private constructors are used to prevent the creation of instances of a class when there are no instance fields or methods, such as the Math class, or when a method is called to obtain an instance of a class. If all the methods in the class are static, consider making the entire class static. For more information see Static Classes and Static Class Members.

```
class NLog
{
    // Private Constructor:
    private NLog() { }

    public static double e = System.Math.E;  //2.71828...
}
```

The following is an example of a class using a private constructor.

```
public class Counter
{
    private Counter() { }
    public static int currentCount;
    public static int IncrementCount()
    {
        return ++currentCount;
    }
}

class TestCounter
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // If you uncomment the following statement, it will generate
        // an error because the constructor is inaccessible:
        // Counter aCounter = new Counter();   // Error

        Counter.currentCount = 100;
        Counter.IncrementCount();
        System.Console.WriteLine("New count: {0}", Counter.currentCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While [this link is related to java](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=40), I think it should help you understand the reason why as the idea is pretty much the same.

> Private constructors prevent a class from being explicitly instantiated by callers. There are some common cases where a private constructor can be useful:
>
> - classes containing only static utility methods
> - classes containing only constants
> - type safe enumerations
> - singletons

Answer (score 1):

You can use it with inheritance in a case where the arguments to the constructor for the base class are of different types to those of the child classes constructor but you still need the functionality of the base class in the child class eg. protected methods.

Generally though this should be avoided wherever possible as this is a bad form of inheritance to be using.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the game, but reading through all the other answers, I don't see this usage mentioned:

I use private constructors in scenarios where I have multiple (public) constructors, and they all have some code in common. With constructor chaining, the code becomes really neat and DRY.

Remember, the private readonly variables can only be set in constructors, so I can't use a regular method.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly int _a;
    private readonly int _b;
    private readonly string _x;

    public MyClass(int a, int b, string x)
        : this(x)
    {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
    }

    public MyClass()
        : this("(not set)")
    {
        // Nothing set here...
    }

    private MyClass(string x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you use private constructors when you are following a singleton design pattern. In this case, you have a static method defined inside the class that internally calls the private constructor.

So to create the instance of the class for the first time, the user calls the classname.static_method_name. In this method, since the class's object doesn't yet exist, the static method internally calls the private constructor and returns the class's instance.

If the class's instance already exists, then the static method simply returns the instance to the calling method.

Answer (score 0):

And of course you can use private constructor to prevent subclassing.